# rally combobox doesn't show properly as expected

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I want to create a combobox listing all user story's formatted id.

The js is somethiing like below:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {

    extend : 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls : 'app',
    launch : function() {
        var usComboBox = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            items : [ {
                xtype : 'rallycombobox',
                storeConfig : {
                    autoLoad : true,
                    model : 'User story',
                    displayField:'FormattedId',
                }
            } ],
        });
        this.add(usComboBox);
    },

});
```

First of all, the comboBox cannot show any formatted id;
Secondly, if I removed the "displayField" config, I can see list of user story names but somehow it's not always showing like that. Sometime if I refresh the page, the list may not be shown. 
I tested this by changing the App.js file and view App-debug.html file in Chrome since Chrome extension terminal couldn't be installed properly in Windows 7. Is this the right way to do?

Comment: Specifically, when loading the page, only the first option is shown in the comboBox. If I click the down icon before the data is populated, then I can see the whole list of options after they are loaded.

Comment: I got it solved by setting autoexpand to true

Comment: but still have trouble showing formatted id in the comboBox.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `filterFieldName` of [rallymultiobjectpicker](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.picker.MultiObjectPicker-cfg-filterFieldName), and fetch FormattedID. It currently does not automatically add the value in `filterFieldName` to the fetch.

```
var box = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'rallymultiobjectpicker',
                modelType: 'userstory',
                filterFieldName: 'FormattedID',
                storeConfig: {
                    fetch:['FormattedID']
                }
            }]
        });
        this.add(box);
```

Comment: many thanks for answer. I may need to use multiple selection later but for this particular case I still need a single selection comboBox. I have managed to show list of formatted ids in the comboBox when loading the page. However, when I clcik the scroll bar, the whole list disappeared and couldn't be shown any more. Is this a bug? I have also tried to config "displayTpl" and "tpl" but failed. My final goal is to show customised options in the comboBox in the format like [ Formatted Id : Name ]. Is this technically possible for now?